# Which Talend components can I use to download files from Sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint, talend

I am using the tFileFech component but it does not download the file, it brings me a blank file, help me please?

I need it to later upload the downloaded file to a sql server database.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You could use tFileFetch to download a file from SharePoint.

1.Create a Job connecting a tFileFetch component to a tLogRow component.
[image]

2.Configure the tFileFetch component.
[image]

a. Select http from the Protocol drop-down menu.

b. In the URI field, provide the URL of the shared document. To get the link, right-click your SharePoint file and select Get a link.
In the URI field, provide the URL of the shared document. To get the link, right-click your SharePoint file and select Get a link.
In the URI field, provide the URL of the shared document. To get the link, right-click your SharePoint file and select Get a link.
[image]

c. In the Destination directory field, enter the folder name where the fetched file will be stored.
d.Enter a file name in the Destination filename field.
e.Clear the POST method check box (enabled by default).

3.On the Advanced settings tab, select the Need authentication check box and provide the Username and Password that you use to access SharePoint.
[image]

4.Run the Job, and locate the HTML file in the destination folder.
[image]

[image: 5.]

5.Open the HTML file, and review the Excel file that is available on SharePoint.
[image]

Comment: Is there any update on this thread? Comment here if you still need any help.